# Creating multiple unique html elements inside a php for loop

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to create a website in my scenario I need to retrieve many rows of data from my database. Each row displayed should have a button next to it with a unique name. The only problem is getting the button to have a unique name.

```
<?php
        require_once 'php/login.php';
        $conn = new mysqli($hn, $un, $pw, $db);
        if ($conn->connect_error) die($conn->connect_error);

        $query = "SELECT * FROM Bets_info WHERE BetGroup = '1'";
        $result = $conn->query($query);
        if(!result) die($conn->error);

        $rows = $result->num_rows;

        for ($j = 0; $j < $rows ; ++$j)
        {
          $result->data_seek($j);
          $row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

          echo '<button id="myBtn">Bet</button>  ';
          echo ' '  .$row['BetWin'] . '/';
          echo ' '  .$row['BetLose']  . ' : ';
          echo ' '  .$row['BetDescription'] . '<br><br>'; 

        }
        $result->close();
        $conn->close();
      ?>
```

I have tried to do the following

```
for ($j = 0; $j < $rows ; ++$j)
        {
          $result->data_seek($j);
          $row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

          echo '<button id="myBtn<? $j ?>">Bet</button>  ';
          echo ' '  .$row['BetWin'] . '/';
          echo ' '  .$row['BetLose']  . ' : ';
          echo ' '  .$row['BetDescription'] . '<br><br>'; 

        }
```

This does not make the buttons called 
btn1, btn2, btn3
but instead it just calls all the buttons `"myBtn<? $j ?>"`.

Comment: Hint: `echo "mybtn{$j}";`

Comment: what you posted is erroring out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for ($j = 0; $j < $rows ; ++$j)
    {
      $result->data_seek($j);
      $row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

      echo '<button id="myBtn'.$j.'">Bet</button>  ';
      echo ' '  .$row['BetWin'] . '/';
      echo ' '  .$row['BetLose']  . ' : ';
      echo ' '  .$row['BetDescription'] . '<br><br>'; 

    }
```

You can not put `<? $j ?>` inside echo

You want to put `'.$j.'` rather than it,
And the code will work fine, :)

I hope its helps you :)

Comment: Cheers i got it working :) !!!

Comment: Click in Accept this answer to make your question as solved question :), And i'm very happy to help you :)

Comment: Yeah it would'nt let me until 15mins had gone past

Comment: My pleasure to help you :)

Answer (score 2):

Concatenate the row number with the . operator, like this:

```
echo '<button id="myBtn' . $j . '">Bet</button>  ';
```

Answer (score 0):

you should do like this :

```
for ($j = 0; $j < $rows ; ++$j)
    {
      $result->data_seek($j);
      $row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

      echo '<button id="myBtn'.$j.'">Bet</button>  ';
      echo ' '  .$row['BetWin'] . '/';
      echo ' '  .$row['BetLose']  . ' : ';
      echo ' '  .$row['BetDescription'] . '<br><br>'; 

    }
```